# Can't set a GridView in a Column

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to set many items into a grid view. But I need to write something above the grid view and that's why I need a column which contains the texts and the grid view. But If I set some text and below the grid view then it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hamim Shop',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('Hamim Shop'),
              GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                children: List.generate(choices.length, (index) {
                  return Center(
                    child: ChoiceCard(choice: choices[index]),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edited from Here:

[image: After adding shrinkWrap: true this error is showed]

Choice Card:

```
class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);

  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(child: Icon(choice.icon, size: 150)),
                Text(choice.title),
              ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

...

```
class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const [
  const Choice(title: 'Car', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  .....
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `shrinkwrap:true` &                   `physics:NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`

**physics:**
Scroll physics that does not allow the user to scroll. Means only Column+SingleChildScrollView Scrolling work.

**shrinkwrap:**

If you do not set the shrinkWrap property, your GridView will be as big as its parent.

If you set it to true, the GridView will wrap its content and be as big as its children allow it to be.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hamim Shop',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('Hamim Shop'),
                GridView.count(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  children: List.generate(choices.length, (index) {
                    return Center(
                      child: ChoiceCard(choice: choices[index]),
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);

  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(child: Icon(choice.icon, size: 150)),
                Text(choice.title),
              ]),
        ));
  }
}
class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const [
const Choice(title: 'Car', icon: Icons.directions_car),
....
];
```

Comment: Bottom overflowed by some pixel.

Comment: @SantoShakil: You can post the screenshot of it, edit your question. Anyhow your question is addressed you can accept the answer now.  Also, show code of ChoiceCard

Comment: the issue is with ChoiceCard(), I need a code to see that, or else you give some extra height to that

Comment: I think, there is no problem with choice card

Comment: @SantoShakil: I have edited the answer, it will work for you now